# protocol not work between two UITbaleViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

The App is designed to let user tap on a cell in Table A, and then go to Table B to add a custom category, finally send this category name back to Table A and change the category label.

It seems not work with the following codes

Table A:

```
class AddNote: UITableViewController, CatDelegate {

    func selectCategory(theCatgory:String){
         customCategory.text = theCatgory
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       // ....
    }
}
```

Table B:

```
protocol CatDelegate:NSObjectProtocol{
    func selectCategory(theCatgory:String)
}

class SetCategory:UITableViewController{

    var theDelegate:CatDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // test to print out the string
        self.theDelegate?.selectCategory("My Category")
    }
   // ......

}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: did you set `theDelegate` to table A?

Comment: assign "theDelegate" to self.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from your code, you do not actually set the delegate when you present your second view controller.

The line

```
self.theDelegate?.selectCategory("My Category")
```

will not call `selectCategory()` nor raise an exception because of the (good practice!) `?` operator if `self.theDelegate` is `nil`. It will just silently do nothing.

As a quick check, you can replace the `?` by `!` for development - it will raise a runtime exception when it encounters `nil`.

Comment: You're right, when I use `!`, the App crash for nil. Actually, this protocol works when using between UIViewController and UIView. I just don't why it doesn't work between two UITableViewControllers.

Comment: Because in that case `viewDidLoad` gets called before you can set the delegate.

Comment: I had tried to place it in `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, it also return nil

Comment: did you set the delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I found the key. I did not set the delegate in Table A.` let Svc : SetCategory = segue.destinationViewController as! SetCategory; Svc.delegate = self`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Table A**

```
In AddNote class 
protocol CatDelegate { /////above class declaration
    func selectCategory(theCatgory:String)
}

class AddNote: NSObject  {
    var theDelegate : CatDelegate?
}
```

In any function in order to fire the delegate function

```
if (self.delegate != nil) {
    self.delegate?. selectCategory("My Category")
}
```

**In Table B**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var addNote : AddNote!
    addNote = AddNote()
    addNote.theDelegate = self
}

func selectCategory(theCatgory:String) {
    ///////// any thing view related
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work, and it seems a reverse. I need to change the label of Table A.